# Trying to use SQL to group accounts by number of sub-types

Tags: sql

I'm using a table that houses account info. These accounts can have between 1 and 6 unique sub types. Currently it only tracks between single and multi subtypes but doesn't show the totals of how many of each multi sub-type account there are (how many accounts with 2 subtypes vs. 3 subtypes and so on). I'm looking for a wholly SQL way to view how many of each grouping of account types.  There are a LOT of accounts in the table so pulling it manually isn't really an option.  Is there a way I can get a count of each of the amount of sub-type groupings?

```
| account | Sub-Type | Single_V_Multi |
|---------|--------- | -------------- |
|123456789|123456789 | Multi          |
|123456789|123456790 | Multi          | 
|123456789|123456791 | Multi          |
|123456792|123456792 | Single         |
|123456793|123456793 | Multi          |
|123456793|123456794 | Multi          |
|123456795|123456795 | Single         |
|123456796|123456796 | Single         |
|123456797|123456797 | Single         |
|123456798|123456798 | Single         |
|123456799|123456799 | Multi          |
|123456799|123456800 | Multi          |
|123456799|123456801 | Multi          |
|123456799|123456802 | Multi          |
```

From this example I'd be looking to get separate counts of the Account column based on the number of unique Sub-Type.  What I've done so far is a query that groups the Sub-Types:

```
SELECT account, COUNT(DISTINCT(Sub-Type)) as BAN_SUB_COUNT
FROM Table
```

Which give the output:

```
| account | BAN_SUB_COUNT |
| ------- | ------------- |
|123456789| 3             |
|123456792| 1             |
|123456793| 2             |
|123456795| 1             |
|123456796| 1             |
|123456797| 1             |
|123456798| 1             |
|123456799| 4             |
```

What I need from this is a way to get a separate count of accounts for each of the distinct BAN_SUB_COUNT entries. Ideally it would be along the lines of:

```
| BAN_SUB_COUNT |count of Accounts|
| ------------- | --------------- |
| 1             | 5               |
| 2             | 1               |
| 3             | 1               |
| 4             | 1               |
```

Sorry for any confusion and I hope I'm explaining myself better here!

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for this data?

Comment: What is that table? And yeah what is your expected result? Kind of hard to help you

Comment: Sorry, first time using this forum, I'm looking for a COUNT of the account column based on number of differing sub-types.  So for this example I'd like something along the lines of COUNT(Sub-Type_1) - 5, COUNT(Sub-Type_2) - 1, COUNT(Sub-Type_3) - 1, COUNT(Sub-Type_4) - 1.  Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well, I'm still fairly new to SQL and feel a little dropped in the deep end.

Comment: @HRoth_Gar Edit and put your expected output in the question, not in comments. Also, your comment says count(sub_type_3) for example, but nowhere in your data do you have a sub_type_3 column.

Comment: @Isolated Thank you for your instruction, I hope this is more clear as to what I'm looking for. Again, apologies for my missteps here!

Comment: @HRoth_Gar So the question is looking better, but you still haven't provided what you would like as your FINAL output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap your query with another one:

```
select ban_sub_count, count(distinct account) as count_of_accounts
from (
  SELECT account, COUNT(DISTINCT Sub-Type ) as BAN_SUB_COUNT
  FROM Table
  group by account
)z
group by ban_sub_count
```

Output:

| BAN_SUB_COUNT | count of Accounts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

Comment: You can replace `count(distinct account)` by a mere `count(*)` as an account can only appear once in the subquery's result.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your question:

```
select a2.*,a.`count_sub_type`
FROM (
    select count(`sub-type`) as count_sub_type,`sub-type` from account group by `sub-type`
) a
left join account a2 on a2.`sub-type` = a.`sub-type`;
```

output :

```
|account |sub-type|single_v_multi|count_sub_type|
|--------|--------|--------------|--------------|
|account6|type1   |multiview     |3             |
|account5|type1   |single        |3             |
|account1|type1   |single        |3             |
|account4|type2   |single        |2             |
|account2|type2   |single        |2             |
|account6|type3   |single        |2             |
|account3|type3   |single        |2             |
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry, first time using this forum and I didn't explain my question very well, I'm looking for a COUNT of the account column based on number of differing sub-types. So for this example I'd like something along the lines of 

| COUNT(Sub-Type_1) | COUNT(Sub-Type_2) | COUNT(Sub-Type_3) | COUNT(Sub-Type_4) |
| - | - | - | - |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Sorry, I'm still fairly new to SQL.